# Image Size in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a command to display someone's avatar in discord such as !avatar <**@user**>/<**userID**>. I want to display the image size as 256 x 256, not 128 x 128. I found a way but now I'm just confused on what's happening here, maybe it's the `user.avatarURL`.

the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Canvas = require('node-canvas');
module.exports = {
name: 'avatar',

async run(message, args) {
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(256, 256);
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        const background = await Canvas.loadImage(user.avatarURL())
        context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'avatar.png')
  .setTitle(user.username)
  .setImage(attachment)
        .setColor('RED');

    message.channel.send(avatarEmbed)
}
```

}

error:

> (node:1464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unsupported image type

the rest is just locations of package files. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write the image from discord.js into a canvas and resend it. Discord embed allows you to use an image URL.

And to get a specific size of avatar you can use options `size`

**Bonus:** options: dynamic is for gif avatar

```js
message.mentions.users.first().displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true })
```

Finally your code can be something like:

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(user.username)
  .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }))
        .setColor('RED');
```

Comment: thank you for the help! I was overthinking it last night